# Using classes from submodules in module tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I have the following structure:

```
api/
  api/
    module1/
      controller/
        controller1.rb
      model/
        model1.rb
      serializer/
        serializer1.rb
```

**controller1.rb** looks like this:

```
class Api::Module1::Controller::Controller1 < ApplicationController
    def index
        # how do I prevent having to use the prefixed full module path ?
        render json: Api::Module1::Model::Model1.all, each_serializer: Api::Module1::Serializer::Serializer1
    end
end
```

**model1.rb** looks like this:

```
class Api::Module1::Model::Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

My question:

How do I circumvent using `Api::Module1::Model` as a prefix to use my model classes in my controller ? I would like to use just `Model1.all` instead of `Api::Module1::Model::Model1.all`.

I tried using `include Api::Module1::Model` at the top of my `controller1.rb` but that doesn't work either because if I then use `Model1.all` it obviously tries to use the module path from the controller, i.e. `Api::Module1::Controller::MenuController::Model`, which is not what I intend to use obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do `Model::Model1.all` (omitting the common root). Is this good enough for you? Imagine that you also have `Serializer::Model1` and `FormObject::Model1`, so you can't just use `Model1`. Otherwise, how will you tell these apart?

```
module Api
  module MyApp
    module Controller
      class Controller1
        attr_reader :model
        def initialize
          @model = Model::User.new
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

module Api
  module MyApp
    module Model
      class User
      end
    end
  end
end

c = Api::MyApp::Controller::Controller1.new
c.model # => #<Api::MyApp::Model::User:0x007fa36411e888>
```

Comment: Yes, I have already used it that way in previous projects, but for some reason it doesn't work. It gives me the following error: `uninitialized constant Api:Module1::Controller::Controller1::Model1`. So for some reason it's using the common root...

Comment: That's weird. Shouldn't happen. Post the actual code you tried.

Comment: Note, `Model::Model1`, **not** just `Model1`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that. I mapped my actual implementation to the example I provided above.

Comment: Must be rails auto-loading (not surprised). What if you `require` model file on top of controller file? Or enable eager-loading?

Comment: I would rather have it working without a hacky solution

Comment: That's not hacking. That's how rails works. Don't like requires (or eager loading) - use FQNs (fully qualified names)

Comment: Well the auto-loader should theoretically pick those up, no ?

Comment: I don't think so. Not enough info to locate the file.

Comment: Actually, forget what I just said.

Comment: It works the first time, when I refresh it won't work anymore on both passenger and rails server.

Comment: the first page load always works, subsequent requests throw the error.

Comment: You just said the same thing. Did you try any of the fixes I suggested? Try the other one :)

Comment: Okay, how do I require the file ? Sorry I'm pretty new to rails/ruby. For me the auto-loader always seemed to work fine...

Comment: put `require 'api/module1/model/model1'` on top of the file

Comment: FYI, eager loading works the first time (and doesn't work after) is because you're running in dev mode with `cache_classes=false`.

Comment: "the auto-loader always seemed to work fine" - that was before you invented file structure that produces names too long to be used :)

Comment: Good point(s). So for production environment `cache_classes` will be `true` ?

Comment: Okay I think I actually found the problem

Comment: I thought `Api::V1::Module1::Controller::Controller1 < ApplicationController` would automatically set up the module structure, but it doesn't ? So if I nest the modules as you demonstrated in your answer, it seems to work. So is my guess correct that those two things are different things ?

Comment: Ah, you see, now the differences start to creep in. API:: **V1** ::Module1? You didn't mention V1 in your question. I assume that the model is not under V1?

Comment: It actually is, just a mistake on my part.

Comment: Ah, I see. Use the full module nesting syntax, not the compact one-line form. That's a quirk of ruby constant resolution mechanism

Comment: The thing I hate about the module nesting is that it clutters my modules **A LOT**. That's why I tried to use the compact form. Strange

Comment: I would have loved to know why the compact syntax doesn't work, but I guess your answer helped me find the problem, so I'll accept it

Comment: @the_critic: yeah, life is pain :)

Comment: It really shouldn't be though. It's supposed to make things easier and I would consider component nesting to be a very significant part of development.... I guess it's just how it is.

Comment: @the_critic: check it out: http://pastie.org/10649156. This is why compact form doesn't work (as it should)

Comment: Okay that's actually really helpful. Thanks! I guess there is some reason they did it that way...